# Product, Subspace and Order Topology

Tags: general-topology

When does product topology , subspace topology and order topology coincide?

Let $ X$ and $Y$ be two ordered sets in their ordered topologies. Let $U$ be a subset of $X$ that is convex in $X$ and $V$ be a subset of $Y$ that is convex in $Y$.

Consider the product topology $X \times Y$.Then will its ordered topology  on $U \times V$ be the same as its subspace topology of $X \times Y$?

Comment: Are we to assume a lexicographic (dictionary) order on the Cartesian products?

Comment: My original question is the first line.(I am not sure whether I have properly framed the question.) Now, if we are n $R\times R$ then one can talk about dictionary order. Can one safely assume that $X$ and $ Y $ have the simple ordered relations with/without dictionary order?

Comment: I just mean that different orders on $U\times V$ will induce different topologies. For example, in general, the dictionary order on $U\times V$ will induce a *very* different topology than the reverse dictionary order (in which the second component is the one that takes precedence), so the answer to your question may depend on the order chosen for $U\times V$.

Comment: Let me give you an example. Say $U$ and $V$ are both the real interval $[0,1]$ in the usual order. Then in the topology induced by the reverse dictionary order, the set $(0,1)\times\{a\}$ is open for any $a\in [0,1],$ but such sets are not open in the topology induced by the dictionary order. Anyway, the upshot is that our choice of order may make a difference.

Comment: @Cameron: I'm interpreting here, but I think when Manasi talks about the "ordered topology on $U \times V$", they mean the product topology coming from the order topology on $U$ and the order topology on $V$. Manasi? Is this correct?

Comment: @Cameron : Thanks. @ Mike : Yes, thats right. My original question is the first line.  Is it possible to add a condition(s) so as to come up with a statement where all three meet?

Comment: Does it make sense to talk about product topology coming from two ordered topologies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Background:**

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces with nonempty subsets $A \subset X$ and  $B \subset Y$. Now, as you've rightly observed, $A \times B$ can be topologised in two natural ways:

1. Give $X \times Y$ its product topology. Then, give $A \times B$ the subspace topology it inherits as a subset of $X \times Y$.
2. Give each of $A$ and $B$ its subspace topology. Then, give $A \times B$ the product topology coming from the topologies on $A$ and $B$.

> **Fact 1:** Both of the above procedures lead to the same topology on $A \times B$.

This fact is standard, and it shouldn't be difficult to find a proof online. It is also not very difficult, so I would encourage you to prove it yourself. Now, it happens that this fact can be refined somewhat with a sort of uniqueness statement.

> **Fact 2:** If $\tau_A$ and $\tau_B$ are topologies on $A$ and $B$ whose product topology $\tau_A \times \tau_B$ (this is notational abuse, the product topology is not really a Cartesian product) equals the topology (2) above, then $\tau_A$ is the subspace topology on $A \subset X$ and $\tau_B$ is the subspace topology on $B \subset Y$.

The reason Fact 2 is true is that, whenever you form a product topological space $X \times Y$, you can recover the topologies on $X$ and $Y$ from the topology on $X \times Y$ by looking at "slices" $\{ (x,y_0)  : x \in X\}$ and $\{ (x_0, y) : y \in Y\}$ where $x_0 \in X$ and  $y_0 \in Y$ are fixed. These slices turn out to be homeomorphic to $X$ and $Y$ under the natural bijections. So, as a consequence,  a product topology on $X \times Y$ is uniquely determined by the input topologies on $X$ and $Y$.

---

**Now we bring in the orders:**

Now, in the situation you describe, $X$ and $Y$ are ordered, and equipped with the order topology. You have selected subsets $U \subset X$ and $V \subset Y$. There are now three natural ways to topologise $U \times V$:

1. Give $X \times Y$ its product topology. Then, give $U \times V$ the subspace topology it inherits as a subset of $X \times Y$.
2. Give each of $U$ and $V$ its subspace topology. Then, give $U \times V$ the product topology coming from the topologies on $U$ and $V$.
3. Consider $U$ and $V$ to be ordered using the suborders inherited from $X$ and $Y$. Then, give each of $U$ and $V$ its order topology. Finally, give $U \times V$ the product topology coming from the order topologies on $U$ and $V$.

Now, procedures (1) and (2) always lead to the same topology on $U \times V$ by Fact 1. Meanwhile, by Fact 2, (2) and (3) will lead to the same topology on $U \times V$ if and only if the input topologies on $U$ and $V$ used to form the product are the same. So, the question you should really be asking is:

> **Question:** Let $X$ be an ordered space and $U \subset X$ a subset. There are two natural ways to topologise $U$.
>
> 1. Make $U$ into an ordered space in its own right by viewing it as a suborder of $X$. Then, give $U$ its order topology.
> 2. Give $X$ its order topology. Then, topologise $U$ as a subspace of $X$.
>
> When are these two topologies on $U$ the same?

Comment: @Mike : Thank You for the detailed explanation. When you bring in the orders, does not one need the property of convexity to talk about them leading to same topology? Munkres, Theorem 16.4, Chapter 2?

Comment: I don't have that book on hand. When you talk about a convex subset of an ordered space, do you just mean an interval? Possibly unbounded in either direction, possibly including or excluding the left/right endpoint?

Comment: pg 90, " Given an ordered set X, let us say that a subset Y of X is convex in X if for each pair of points $a<b$ of Y, the entire interval (a,b) of points of X lies in Y. " This  I think is in R. Now , suppose it is not in R, then does one need some other condition?

Comment: Your definition sounds like it is just a more concise way of saying $Y$ is an interval of one of the types I mentioned above. Anyway, that condition definitely suffices to make the order topology and subspace topology on $Y$ agree. Much weaker conditions are possible.

Comment: Theorem 16.4 : Let X be an ordered set in the order topology. Let Y be a subset of X that is convex in X. Then the order topology of Y is the same as the topology Y inherits as a subspace of X.

Comment: Sounds like Theorem 16.4 answers your question.

Comment: I was not sure so I posted cos I wondered what would happen to the product topology.

Comment: Sounds like means there is a possibility.. or it does ???

Comment: Yes. If $U$ and $V$ are convex subsets of ordered spaces $X$ and $Y$, then all of the topologies (1), (2) and (3) from the 2nd half of my answer are the same topology.

Comment: I just need to go through this again tomorrow. If I have more questions I'll ask them tomorrow or I'll just check with  you about the weaker conditions!Thanks so much.

Comment: By weaker conditions, is it what you have mentioned above " procedures (1) and (2) always lead to the same topology on U×V by Fact 1. Meanwhile, by Fact 2, (2) and (3) will lead to the same topology on U×V if and only if the input topologies on U and V used to form the product are the same."

Comment: @Manasi: I think if you have a new question you should probably post it as a new question so the comment section here doesn't become too clogged up.

Comment: @Mike:Okay Thanks.